# C# and email: HREF to a file attached/embedded in the mail itself

Tags: c#, html-email, email-attachments

I'm implementing some code in C# to send emails in HTML format. I need to be able to embedded images and links to a document which is attached to the mail itself.

I had no big issues with the images. I create an `AlternateView`, create a `LinkedResource` for each image, replace the image `src` with a `CID`, then add each `LinkedResource` to the view and that's it. It works, no big deal.

Simplified, something like this:

```
private void EmbedImage(AlternateView htmlView, string imageFile)
{
    LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(imageFile, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    _htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

    _body.Replace("ImagePlaceholderTag " + imageFile, "cid:" + inline.ContentId);
}
```

The problem happens if I try to do something similar with a PDF.

Let's say I have a document `conditions.pdf`. What I need to do is to attach the document to the email and then have an `href` in the body of the mail that will open the document when clicked.

I can do this easily on a standard HTML page, obviously, so I've tried to apply the same logic I've used for the images with the only difference being:

1. I use `MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf`.
2. Instead of using the `cid`: for the `src` of an `img` I use it for the `href` of an `<a>` tag.

Result: I get a link in the mail, but when I click it the browser tries to open the `cid` file.

What should I do to obtain the behavior I need?

Comment: If you send an attachment through Outlook or another email program, what kind of HTML does it generate? Can you compare that to what yours is doing?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. I have never seen a link within an email that opens an attachment. Usually one either **1.** hosts the PDF somewhere and provides a link to it, or **2.** Attach the document to the email and have language that tells the user to check attachments. If there is a way to do this, I would certainly like to know how.

Comment: @mjwills: I don't have access to such advanced mail client. I have only a webmail address, and the editor is quite basic. And that said, I can't see the source of the messages anyway.

Comment: @JuanR it's confusing to me, too. I think I've seen something like that a few times, but I may be wrong. What bugger me is that it is actually supported by the .NET framework, you can create mail messages with embedded pdf documents, assigne them a cid, without getting any kind of error. The mail works, too, it get delivered, there is the link and it points to the right CID, it's just the mail client that ignores it...

Comment: @motoDrizzt: Well, email clients are not exactly known for reliable displaying emails. Either way, I suggest you read the specification and see if what you are trying to do is supported: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045

Comment: `And that said, I can't see the source of the messages anyway.` Send them to https://www.guerrillamail.com/ . You can view the raw source there. But @JuanR may be right - it is possible that you are asking for an option 3 when only options 1 and 2 work.